# Efficiently finding all children before a certain index in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I'm iterating through a table of data in jQuery, and I need to do some operations on the first *n* `td` elements in each `tr`. Currently, I'm using the following structure to do this:

```
$('#tableID').find('tr').each(function(){
    $(this).children('td').each(function(i){
        if(i < n){do_some_stuff_to(this)}
    }
}
```

My concern is that, when the table grows large, I may run into some performance issues with iterating through each `td` element in the row and running an if statement. It may also be that this if statement doesn't take a significant amount of time to run compared to `do_some_stuff`, but it still feels sloppy.

What I'd like to do is limit my selection to all children with an index less than *n*. Something like the `:nth-children(n)` selector, but with everything preceding the index also returned in my jQuery selector. Is there a way of doing this without looping through each child of each row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be the [**lt()**](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector (lower than) :

```
$('#tableID tr td:lt(10)')
```

> Select all elements at an index less than the index given within the matched
>   set.